# Magento 2 Ui Component how to upload image and save it

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, backend

```
    <column name="image" class="Vendor\mpdule-name\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Thumbnail">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

This is what i have so far but i am not sure what should be in the class
also i am not sure how to add it into installSchema